# How do I place a colon into a string two characters from the end using Perl?

Tags: perl, string

I'm trying to find a way to place a colon ( : ) into a string, two characters from the end of the string.

Examples of $meetdays:
1200  => 12:00
900 => 9:00
1340 =>13:40

Not sure if this should be a regular expression or just another function that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s/(?=..$)/:/
```

Don't use roe's suggestion of `$&`.  perldoc perlvar:

> The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches.  See "BUGS".

Comment: As always, there are more than one way. There's a performance penalty yes, but it was the first pattern that came to mind (yes, I'm a sed guy originially of course), and it's probably fast enough in this case, don't you think? :)

Comment: it was fast enough.. its a really small script anyway... ayrnieu's solution worked too

Comment: The point is not whether it is fast or not. The point is that newcomers shouldn't get into the habit of using $& in the first place.

Comment: Why use the fancy "zero-width positive lookahead" operator (?=) when an ordinary s/(..)$/:$1/ would work fine, including in older versions of Perl (and even in many non-Perl regex implementations) where ?= doesn't work?

Comment: I expect pain from non-Perl regex implementations; I don't hurt myself in anticipation of them.  You'll have to go back farther than ten years to find a perl that doesn't support zero-width lookaheads.

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't realise zero-width lookaheads were introduced in Perl 5 -- I assumed they were more recent than that.

Comment: Since this question somehow got to be a matter of slow vs fast code: s/(?=..$)/:/ is 26 times slower than s/(..)$/$1/ with perl 5.10 and 13 times slower with perl 5.8

Comment: @Manni: Interesting.  I know that Perl optimises some common cases in regexes, e.g. those ending in "$" -- maybe that optimisation is not done for lookahead expressions.  In that case I imagine it will eventually be addressed by the Perl core developers.

Comment: You really can't claim relative speediness. It depends on various things like the compiler that built perl, the various options, etc. You can get away with saying it's slower, but your relative results are only valid for your own configuration.

Answer (score 9):

Can also use [substr()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) as well.....

```
my $string = "1200";
substr $string, -2, 0, ':';

# $string => '12:00';
```

Comment: I would imagine the substr() is significantly faster as well as easier to read and more intuitive.

Comment: More intuitive only if you don't know regexes well enough.

Comment: this one looks intuitive... dont know why, but it created 20~ lines in the csv file and then took a dump and gave me this error... substr outside of string at ./test3 line 237. - my best guess is that it ran into a value of 0, which happens in my data and is not bad data, just implies a diff event

Comment: "substr outside of string" error means that you have data in your CSV that is less than 2 characters wide.  Thus it cannot insert the ':' two chars (-2) from the end.   If u have "diff event" then you need to filter use of the substr or regex accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
s/..$/:$&/
```

it matches two-characters at the end of the string, and replaces it with a colon, and the matched string (i.e. the two characters).

**EDIT**
Fixed sed-backref to the perl equivalent.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't the most optimized expression, but it's easy to understand and does the trick, how was that unhelpful (as in downvote)? Isn't upvoting the better answer the SO way?

Comment: Quoting from perlvar: "The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches.". Don't use $&!

Comment: Seriously, have you people not heard of solve first, optimize later IF there's a performance problem? I already admitted it's not the most optimized (will you stop beating it into the ground already?), but it does the trick, and it's easy to grasp.

Comment: Please don't attack a perfectly valid solution, promote the better one instead.

Comment: roe: the perl documentation says not to use it *ever* because *all* regex in *all* included files take a *significant* performance hit. Seeing regex is used everywhere, i think its fair to *not* make it slower *everywhere* at once, when there is an easier way to solve the problem without the penalty

Comment: Very well, this is what mine says: "So avoid $& , $' , and $` if you can, but if you can't (and some algorithms really appreciate them), once you've used them once, use them at will, because you've already paid the price. As of 5.005, $&  is not so costly as the other two.".

Comment: I don't see a "not ever", and I certainly do see an "at will" if it has already been used. If you're so worried about all the included files, are you sure none of them uses it? What if this is a one-liner which runs in a split second even with $&? For the problem at hand the solution is still valid.

Comment: definately worked, but im using ayrnieu's because everyone seems to be allergic to $& - thanks anyway, don't know why people are taking such offense to that usage haha

Comment: The same reason why you should always use a sledgehammer when driving in nails; there exists cases where the regular hammer is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

roe's answer "works" , but its rather inobvious regex.

I would more go for

```
s/(^.*)(..$)/$1:$2/
```

Because I just *love* backrefs.

Its overkill for what you're doing, but to me its more semantically expressive.

Comment: the first capture is a bit wasted, why not simply s/(..$)/:$1/ ?

Comment: Although the first part is really redundant, it is a lot more readable. ( At least to the way I parse regex  )

Comment: +1 blixtor.  @Kent: although it makes no practical difference in this case, your original answer is slower since Perl will need to backtrack two characters to match the final "..".  If that ".." was a more complicated expression, the initial ".*" could easily make it *much* slower.

Answer (score -2):

The Perl equivalent of sed's & is $&, so it should be:

```
 $s = s /..$/:$&/s;
```