# How can I insert a decimal point before the last three digits of a number?

Tags: perl

I have a number and need to add a decimal to it for formatting.

The number is guaranteed to be between 1000 and 999999 (I have covered the other possibilities in other ways, this is the one I can't get my head around). I need to put a decimal before the last 3 digits, for example:

```
1000   -> 1.000
23513  -> 23.513
999999 -> 999.999
```

How can I do  this?

Comment: Regular expressions are a versatile tool, but they're not the *only* tool. What makes you so sure they're the right tool for formatting a number?

Comment: Big warning with this one. Using a regular expression can lead to some unexpected behavior if you are manipulating the numbers in perl. On my machine, if I do `my $num = 11745.041 - 11739.7; print $num;`, it outputs: "5.34099999999853". Applying the regex listed in Adam's accepted answer before the print statement changes that to "5.34099999999.853". Probably not what you're looking for. Using `$num = sprintf('%.3f', $num);` like the answer by @draegtun, produces the expected: "5.341".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$num =~ s/(\d{3})$/.$1/
```

That says: Take a block of 3 digits (that must be anchored at the END of the string) and replace them with a "`.`" followed by whatever was just matched.

Comment: This is not the best answer; see below for draegtun's response which is preferable.

Comment: Actually it *is* the best answer to the question that was asked, though possibly not the best way to accomplish the task at hand. The question specifically asked for a regular expression.

Answer (score 44):

And yet another way for fun of it ;-)

```
my $num_3dec = sprintf '%.3f', $num / 1000;
```

Comment: I think that this too clearly expresses the meaning of the input data, and should be avoided in favor of something more mysterious  :-)

Comment: +1 This is the right answer to the question. The fact that the OP mistakenly believed a regex substitution was needed does not change that.

Comment: No, this isn't necessarily *the* right answer to the question.  If you have a 64bit perl and >15 digit numbers, this may well be the wrong answer, while the substr or s/// will always work.

Comment: @ysth: Yes but question was limited to 1000 - 999999 (integers) so it is actually "the right answer" ;-)

Comment: Correct.  Especially has the re & substr solutions provided won't work if number is less than 1000 ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Here is another solution just for the fun of it:

In Perl substr() can be an lvalue which can help in your case.

```
substr ($num , -3 , 0) = '.';
```

will add a dot before the last three digits.

You can also use the four arguments version of substr (as pointed in the comments) to get the same effect:

```
substr( $num, -3, 0, '.' );
```

I would hope it is more elegant / readable than the regexp solution, but I am sure it will throw off anyone not used to substr() being used as an lvalue.

Comment: Better written as "`substr( $num, -3, 0, '.' );`"

Comment: Yep!  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505028/how-do-i-place-a-colon-into-a-string-two-characters-from-the-end-using-perl/505279#505279

Answer (score 2):

Golf anyone?

```
substr $num,-3,0,'.';
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something here? If you have a number between 999999 and 1000 that should represent a number between 999.999 and 1.000 you should be able to just:

$num /= 1000.000;

/PF

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$num = reverse $num;
$num =~ s/\d{3}(?=\d)/$&./g;
$num = reverse $num;
```