# How to move the decimal point N places to the left efficiently?

Tags: string, perl, decimal

I have a bunch of decimal numbers (as strings) which I receive from an API. I need to 'unscale' them, i.e. divide them by some power of 10. This seems a  simple [task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301266/275088) for integers, but I have *decimals* with no guaranteed range. So, basically I need a function that works like this:

```
move_point "12.34" 1; # "1.234"
move_point "12.34" 5; # "0.0001234"
```

I'd rather not use floats to avoid any rounding errors.

Comment: I would be curious to know the execution time between a text processing solution and the one where you convert the value then do the proper division.

Comment: @LucM That would be like comparing apples and oranges, since division could introduce rounding errors that the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit verbose, but should do the trick:

```
sub move_point {
    my ($n, $places) = @_;

    die 'negative number of places' if $places < 0;
    return $n if $places == 0;

    my ($i, $f) = split /\./, $n;  # split to integer/fractional parts

    $places += length($f);

    $n = sprintf "%0*s", $places+1, $i.$f;  # left pad with enough zeroes
    substr($n, -$places, 0, '.');  # insert the decimal point
    return $n;
}
```

Demo:

```
my $n = "12.34";

for my $p (0..5) {
    printf "%d  %s\n", $p, move_point($n, $p);
} 

0  12.34
1  1.234
2  0.1234
3  0.01234
4  0.001234
5  0.0001234
```

Comment: Well done. You can change the pattern to `/([^.]*)\.?(.*)/` to make it work with integers too.

Comment: @Casimir: good point. Another alternative is to use `split /\./, $n`

Comment: Upvoted but if `$places` is supposed to be non-negative, you should check that.

Comment: Actually, and probably more importantly, you'd also need to check for `$n` being `0` (see warnings). Also, should `0.0` become `0.000000`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"%0*s"`to avoid the needless conversion to numbers?

Comment: The API returns decimal numbers that are > 0.

Comment: @planetp: This solution requires that the power of ten is always non-negative. It also doesn't support values without a decimal point. Are these valid assumptions?

Comment: @Borodin: Well, it *does* support values without a decimal point (did you try it yourself at all?). I didn't bother to clear the warnings in that case though as OP clearly stated they used decimals.

Comment: @eugeney: My comment was to the OP, and I was asking for more information about the nature of the problem, but okay. Well in my book a program that runs with warnings is broken. The OP says *"This seems a simple task for integers, but I have decimals with no guaranteed range"* which I took to mean that they have *both* integers and decimals, but that help is needed only for the latter case. I don't think it's ideal to use two solutions, selected according to whether a value contains a decimal point

Answer (score 1):

Unless your data has contains values with significantly more digits than you have shown then a floating-point value has more than enough accuracy for your purpose. Perl can reliably reproduce up to 16-digit values

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

say move_point("12.34", 1); # "1.234"
say move_point("12.34", 5); # "0.0001234"
say move_point("1234", 12);
say move_point("123400", -9);

sub move_point {
    my ($v, $n) = @_;

    my $dp = $v =~ /\.([^.]*)\z/ ? length $1 : 0;
    $dp += $n;
    $v /= 10**$n;

    sprintf '%.*f', $dp < 0 ? 0 : $dp, $v;
}
```

#### output

```
1.234
0.0001234
0.000000001234
123400000000000
```

---

#### Update

If the limits of standard floating-point numbers are actually insuffcient for you then the core [`Math::BigFloat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat) will do what you need

This program shows a number with sixteen digits of accuracy, multiplied by everything from 10E-20 to 10E20

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Math::BigFloat;

for ( -20 .. 20 ) {
    say move_point('1234567890.1234567890', $_);
}

sub move_point {
    my ($v, $n) = @_;

    $v = Math::BigFloat->new($v);

    # Build 10**$n
    my $mul = Math::BigFloat->new(10)->bpow($n);

    # Count new decimal places
    my $dp = $v =~ /\.([^.]*)\z/ ? length $1 : 0;
    $dp += $n;

    $v->bdiv($mul);
    $v->bfround(-$dp) if $dp >= 0;
    $v->bstr;
}
```

#### output

```
123456789012345678900000000000
12345678901234567890000000000
1234567890123456789000000000
123456789012345678900000000
12345678901234567890000000
1234567890123456789000000
123456789012345678900000
12345678901234567890000
1234567890123456789000
123456789012345678900
12345678901234567890
1234567890123456789
123456789012345678.9
12345678901234567.89
1234567890123456.789
123456789012345.6789
12345678901234.56789
1234567890123.456789
123456789012.3456789
12345678901.23456789
1234567890.123456789
123456789.0123456789
12345678.90123456789
1234567.890123456789
123456.7890123456789
12345.67890123456789
1234.567890123456789
123.4567890123456789
12.34567890123456789
1.234567890123456789
0.1234567890123456789
0.01234567890123456789
0.001234567890123456789
0.0001234567890123456789
0.00001234567890123456789
0.000001234567890123456789
0.0000001234567890123456789
0.00000001234567890123456789
0.000000001234567890123456789
0.0000000001234567890123456789
0.00000000001234567890123456789
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly what scale I may need to apply, so better to be on the safe side.

Comment: @planetp: Please take a look at my update. `Math::BigFloat` is a core part of Perl, and is intended exactly for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks. Are there any performance benefits, compared to the string version?

Comment: @planetp: I don't know. I would guess that the string version is a lot faster, but a quick benchmark shows that a single call to my own code takes 300 microseconds and it's highly unlikely to be a bottleneck in your program. You should choose the version that you think is clearest and most understandable